# What is static and dynamic payload types in SDP ? What is the difference between them?

Tags: sdp

I am trying to understand the difference between static and dynamic payloads in SDP protocol but haven't arrived at any conclusion. Can someone please elaborate on whats the difference and why dynamic payload is required ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [draft](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-wu-avtcore-dynamic-pt-usage-02.html) as the basis for your search.

The payload format specification is described in [RFC3550](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550). RTP Payload type can have the values 0 to 127. The binding of RTP payload format to Payload type can be static or dynamic.

[Section 6 of RFC 3551](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3551#section-6) enumerates the static payload types.

Quoting section 3 of above draft:

> As described in section 3 of RFC3551 [RFC3551], the payload type number space is relatively small and cannot accommodate assignments for all existing and future encodings. The registry for RTP Payload types (PT) for standard audio and video encodings [...] is closed. New payload formats(e.g.,H.264,VP8) MUST use dynamic payload type number assignment.

I hope this helps.